# JSON editor which shows results of embedding other schema

Tags: json, validation, reference, embed, jsonschema

I am using the eclipse plugin json editor found here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsejsonedit/

This plugin, as well as several websites I have tried, does not appear to show the results of using a $ref. For example, I have a file which contains a $ref to an online schema:

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  "address": {"$ref": "http://domain/commons.json#address"}
}
}
```

I've also tried just referring to a local schema:

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  "address": {"$ref": "myLocalSchema.json#address"}
}
}
```

In both cases the json tree shows these entries to simply be a string underneath the object. I would expect a reference to expand the tree with whatever content is found in the reference. Is this a normal shortcoming of JSON editing tools? If so, how can I be sure I have properly referred to the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse Json editor is not a Json-Schema editor, so I would not expect any href resolution from it (or any other JSON editor that does not offer Json-Schema features).

There exist an [json-schema validator plugin for Eclipse](https://github.com/sabina-jung/JSON-Schema-Validation-Eclipse).